# If for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ the rank of the derivative $Df(x)$ is 2, prove that the image of $f$ is an open set.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I don't see how to solve the following problem, any suggestions?

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $f\in C^{1}$. If  for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ the rank of the derivative $Df(x)$ is 2, prove that the image of $f$ is an open set.

Would someone please help me on this question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean rank of the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $g:R^2\times R\rightarrow R^3$ defined by $g(x,y,z)=(f(x,y),z)$ shows that the rank of the differential is 3 and deduce that it is a local diffeomorphism by using the local inversion theorem, then consider the composition of $g$ with the projection (which is an open map) on $R^2$ which is $f$.